# firm and year fixed effect regression using xtreg without a dependent dummy variable

Tags: stata, fixed-effects-model

I have an econometric problem. I have a firm level panel database. I want to see the impact of the reduction of tariffs on the wage bill at the firm level. So I regress wages on input tariff, output tariff, and a dummy if the firm is an exporting firm.

I run this type of regression:

```
xtreg log_wages lagged_sales input_tar_exporter input_tar output_tar exporter I.year, fe, if year > 1997
```

I don't know if this can work. I have results that are relevant but I thought that xtreg could only work if the dependent variable is a dummy.

Comment: if my answer solved your problem, don't forget to mark it as solved. :)

Answer (score 1):

`xtreg` is a generic panel data command, which can accommodate different type of dependent variables, either continuous, discrete, or dichotomous. There is no a-priori restriction.

If you see the help file in Stata (`help xtreg`), you can see no mention of such restriction. In fact, the (only) example is that where the dependent variable is log of wages, just as in your case.

You can go further and check the [Manual](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/xt.pdf) for panel data commands (Stata 13). In page 366 you find a theoretical background of panel data estimation, related to what the particular command and options are doing. There you can see that there is no such "dummy variable" restriction on $y_{it}$.